# Why does replacing an argument with its value cause an error?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm fairly new to C++, and I wanted to test what I know about it by implementing a mediocre List class.

List.hpp:

```
#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

// Only supports int lists up to 100 items for now.

class List
{
    public:
        List(int arr[], int length);
        void append(int item);
        void print();
        void remove();
        int len();
        List operator+(List obj);
    protected:
    private:
        int *list = new int[100];
        int size = 0;
};

#endif
```

List.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.hpp"

List::List(int arr[], int length)
: size(length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        list[i] = arr[i];
    }
}

void List::append(int item)
{
    list[size] = item;
    size++;
}

void List::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            std::cout << '[';
        }
        std::cout << list[i];
        if (i == size - 1)
        {
            std::cout << ']' << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
}

void List::remove()
{
    if (size == 0) { 
        std::cout << "Error: list is empty" << std::endl; 
        return; 
    } 
    else { 
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { 
            list[i] = list[i + 1]; 
        } 
        size--; 
    } 
}

int List::len()
{
    return size;
}

List List::operator+(List obj)
{
    List res({}, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        res.append((this->list)[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++)
        res.append((obj.list)[i]);
    res.size = this->size + obj.size;
    return res;
}
```

However, upon initializing `List mylist({1, 2, 3}, 3);`, the compiler says,

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:29: error: no matching function for call to 'List::List(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, int)'
     List mylist({1, 2, 3}, 3);
                             ^
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
List.hpp:9:9: note: candidate: List::List(int*, int)
         List(int arr[], int length);
         ^~~~
List.hpp:9:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int*'
List.hpp:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr List::List(const List&)
 class List
       ^~~~
List.hpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
List.hpp:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr List::List(List&&)
List.hpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

But when I intialize `mylist` using

```
int myarr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
List mylist(myarr, 3);
```

it works perfectly.  Why is this so?

Comment: Using an `initializer_list<int>` as the parameter of the constructor would simplify the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `List mylist({1, 2, 3}, 3);`, `{1, 2, 3}` isn't an array, its a [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: If {1, 2, 3} is a std::initializer_list, then is the only reason why myarr is an array the "int" and the "[3]"?

Comment: You definitely do _not_ want to use `new` here.  That leaks the allocated memory.

Comment: `myarr` is an array because it is declared as an array type, `<type> <name>[<size>]` is the syntax for an array, yes. Technically, `{1, 2, 3}` is NOT a `std::initializer_list`, it is a `braced-init-list`, just as the error message says. It has no type of its own, but it gets parsed based on context. If `List` had a constructor that accepted `std::initializer_list` then the compiler would be able to create a `std::initializer_list` object from the `braced-init-list` and pass it to the constructor due to [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).